# Hide bottom navigation bar - shows white strip at bottom

Tags: android

I need to hide Bottom Navigation Bar.
    I used these flag as :

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
But blank white strip appears at bottom of device.
How to remove that?
```

I have flow like this MainActivity - > HomeFragment - > InventoryFragment.
In InventoryFragment i want to remove navigation bar.

Comment: What is the background color of layout that you are facing on?

Comment: @Anurag Singh white strip appears

Comment: I want to know color of layout background and not strip.

Comment: for layout background i used white color....but  strip color is not exactly white

Comment: Just use yellow color for layout background and let me know if white strip changes to yellow.

Comment: still strip color is same white

Answer (score 1):

Replace `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE` with `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY`

**AppCompatActivity code:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

**Xml Layout file:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFE744"
tools:context="....">
```

**APP theme:**

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_black</item>
</style>
```

**AppCompatActivity theme is same as application theme**

Comment: still same effect using View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY

Comment: So strange. Post the app theme and activity theme for on which you are checking. Also your layout xml file.

Comment: application theme ---- > <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

Comment: activity theme ----> <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

Comment: Just FYI View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE you are using twice.

Comment: thnks @anurag singh for helping me but it does not solve the issue

Comment: I tried all the options and it is working fine on my end. Why not on your end is making me crazy.

Comment: You didn't post layout file that I asked above?

Comment: plz share with me ur application and activity theme

Comment: my layout file is too large thats why not posted...bt is that file matters ?

Comment: You try with the above code that I updated. It's Just to check if any issue is there.